# How to load antd font from local?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I 've been using customise-cra and react-rewired for providing global styles for antd components, i've to change font for antd all components. and the font is stored in local folder, is there any way to load local font using less variables?

[I've done by refering this documentation](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#Advanced-Guides)

Comment: More reference - https://ant.design/docs/spec/font
Or if you want to use your own font-family, then you can override with your custom style sheet and you can use the non-websafe file from a local repo.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was doing, i wanted to know if i can do it by using modifyVars()